# Seleccionar parte del pathname

Tags: javascript

Me interesa obtener un texto  del pathname, por ejemplo si el link es **https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask** me gustaría poder obtener simplemente el **questions** o el **ask**.

```js
function seleccionar() {
  var pathnam = window.location.pathname;
  document.getElementById("path").innerHTML = pathnam;
}
```

```css
#path{
color: #fff;
padding: 5px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="path"></div>
<button onclick="seleccionar()">Obtener</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener las distintas partes del `path` podrías usar [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function seleccionar() {
  var pathnam = window.location.pathname;
  var parts = pathnam.substr(1).split('/');
  document.getElementById("path").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(parts);
}
```

```css
#path{
color: #fff;
padding: 5px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="path"></div>
<button onclick="seleccionar()">Obtener</button>
```

Puntualmente:

- Para el caso `window.loaction.href = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'`
- Obtendrás `parts = ["questions", "ask"]`
- Para recuperar `"questions"` bastaría con usar `parts[0]`